# Android Media Process detected above threshold

Tags: gallery

I'm sure a lot of us stumble upon following issue: **> android media process detected above threshold**.

I've spend a lot of time reading Google and various different forums and yet I still have no solution. I outlined some of the things that I've done on my blog [Android Media Process (high CPU) | alexus' blog](http://alexus.org/howto/android-media-process-high-cpu), i.e.:

- Settings -> Apps -> ALL -> Media Storage -> “Force stop” & “Clear data”.
- Gallery (deleting broken images (black/grey image place holder/square).

yet still nothing( I even did following:

```
~ # e2fsck /dev/block/mmcblk0p12
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p12: clean, 82292/1875968 files, 3972208/7493115 blocks
~ #
```

so seems like my "sdcard" is in good state yet as soon as I start my Android phone it takes about ~10min and ~10%-30% of my battery to complete this cycle of whatever is it doing after booting my phone(.

just in case if anyone cares I'm using Samsung Galaxy Nexus (toro/Verizon) w/ Google Jelly Bean (4.1.1).